# How to show Y number of custom posts after every X normal posts?

Tags: custom-post-types, loop

I have a loop within a loop.
I figured out how to show all or X number of custom posts after Y number of normal posts.
I also figured out how to show 1 custom post after every Y normal posts.
How do I show X custom posts after EVERY Y number of normal posts.

In simple terms.
How do I show 2 book (custom post type) posts after every 4 blog posts?
How does one fetch more than 1 post at a time from the loop?

this is the logic of the x custom posts after y normal posts.
how do i get x custom posts after EVERY y normal posts?

```
main query // normal query
$k=0 // setting iterator
while have posts, the post

---post markup---


if($k == 4 or $k % 4 == 0) { // whether after x number or after every x number
second query // using WP_Query
while second query has posts, the posts

---custom post type markup // I NEED TO SHOW MORE THAN ONE HERE IF IT IS AFTER EVERY X blogposts

endwhile; //second query ends

}

$k++;
endwhile // main query
```

Comment: Can you provide some additional detail of what happens/doesn't work when you run your code?

Comment: The logic I have posted above is for x posts AFTER y posts.
I can't figure out the logic for x posts EVERY y posts.
So currently I am making do with x posts AFTER y posts as I don't know how I can get more posts AT A TIME from the loop...

Comment: @thedigitalmonk Any progress on this problem?

Comment: @birgire I am so sorry for not following up on this. Yes I tried your code and it worked perfectly! But then the client added another requirement where things had to be loaded via Ajax and I lost it there. Another developer took over and rewrote the entire thing.

However I am going to use this on new projects. Hopefully a case will come soon. I am very grateful for the help!

Comment: @thedigitalmonk ok great, no problem, best of luck with your new projects.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's an idea:

### Definitions:

- Posts per page: `PPP`
- Custom post type: `Y`
- Main query post type: `X`
- How many `Y` posts to inject each time: `y`
- How many `X` posts to display before injecting the `Y` posts: `x`

### Formula:

We will use:

```
    PPP(Y) = y * floor( ( PPP(X) -1 ) / x )
```

where `PPP(X)`, `x` and `y` are positive.

### Examples:

Setup 1:

```
PPP(X)=1, x=3, y=2, PPP(Y) = 2 * floor( (1-1)/3 ) = 2 * 0 = 0
Loop: X
```

Setup 2:

```
PPP(X)=3, x=3, y=2, PPP(Y) = 2 * floor( (3-1)/3 ) = 2 * 0  = 0
Loop: XXX
```

Setup 3:

```
PPP(X)=4, x=3, y=2, PPP(Y) = 2 * floor( (4-1)/3 ) = 2 * 1  = 2
Loop: XXX YY X
```

Setup 4:

```
PPP(X)=11, x=3, y=2, PPP(Y) = 2 * floor( (11-1)/3 )  = 2 * 3 = 6
Loop: XXX YY XXX YY XXX YY XX
```

Setup 5:

```
PPP(X)=12, x=3, y=2, PPP(Y) = 2 * floor( (12-1)/3 ) = 2 * 3 = 6
Loop: XXX YY XXX YY XXX YY XXX
```

Setup 6:

```
PPP(X)=13, x=3, y=2, PPP(Y) = 2 * floor( (13-1)/3 ) = 2 * 4 = 8 
Loop: XXX YY XXX YY XXX YY XXX YY X
```

### Strategy:

Let's try to find a way to inject the `Y` posts into the loop of `X` posts, without modifying the template files directly.

We want to hook into the `loop_start` action for the main query of post type `X`, and fetch `PPP(Y)` posts of type `Y`.

Then we want to use the `the_post` hook to display:

```
get_template_part( 'content', 'y' );
```

We can use the for example the `current_post` and `posts_per_page` properties of the main `$wp_query` object to control the injection logic.

I think it's easier to call `WP_Query()` for each injection, but let's constrain ourselves to call it only **once** before the main loop.

### Implementation:

Create a template part file in your active theme's directory, for example `content-page.php`, containing:

```
<article>
    <header class="entry-header">
        <h2 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
    </header>
    <div class="entry-content">
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    </div>
</article>
```

Then you can try the following:

```
add_action( 'wp', function(){

    // We want the injection only on the home page:
    if( ! is_home() ) return;

    // Start the injection:
    $inject = new WPSE_Inject( array( 
        'items_before_each_inject' => 3, 
        'cpt_items_per_inject'     => 2, 
        'cpt'                      => 'page',
        'template_part'            => 'content-page',
        'paged'                    => ( $pgd = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? $pgd : 1,       
    ) );
    $inject->init();
});
```

and modify it to your needs.

The `WPSE_Inject` class is defined as:

```
/**
 * class WPSE_Inject
 *
 * Inject custom posts into the main loop, through hooks, 
 * with only a single WP_Query() call
 *
 * @link http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/141612/26350
 *
 * Definitions:
 *      Posts per page: PPP
 *      Custom post type: Y
 *      Main query post type: X
 *      How many Y posts to inject: y
 *      How many X posts to display before injecting the Y posts: x
 *
 * Formula:
 *      PPP(Y) = y * floor( ( PPP(X) -1 ) / x ) 
 *          where PPP(X), x and y are positive
 */

class WPSE_Inject
{   
    protected $results       = NULL;
    protected $query         = NULL;
    protected $nr            = 0;
    protected $inject_mode   = FALSE;
    protected $args          = array();

    public function __construct( $args = array() )
    {
        $defaults = array( 
            'items_before_each_inject' => 5, 
            'cpt_items_per_inject'     => 1, 
            'cpt'                      => 'post', 
            'paged'                    => 1, 
            'template_part'            => 'content-post'
        );
        $this->args = wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults );
    }

    public function init()
    {
        add_action( 'loop_start', array( $this, 'loop_start' ) );
        add_action( 'loop_end',   array( $this, 'loop_end'   ) );
    }

    public function cpt_items_on_this_page( WP_Query $query )
    {
        $count =  $this->args['cpt_items_per_inject'] * floor( ( $query->get( 'posts_per_page' ) -1 ) / $this->args['items_before_each_inject'] );
        return ( $count > 0 ) ? $count : 1;
    }

    public function loop_start( WP_Query $query )
    {
        $this->query = $query;

        if( $query->is_main_query() )
        {               
            $args = array( 
                'post_type'        => $this->args['cpt'], 
                'posts_per_page'   => $this->cpt_items_on_this_page( $query ), 
                'paged'            => $this->args['paged'], 
                'suppress_filters' => TRUE, 
            );
            $this->results = new WP_Query( $args );
            add_action( 'the_post', array( $this, 'the_post' ) );
        }
    }

    public function loop_end( WP_Query $query )
    {
        if( $query->is_main_query() )
            remove_action( 'the_post', array( $this, 'the_post' ) );
    }

    public function the_post()
    {           
        if( ! $this->inject_mode        
            && 0 < $this->nr 
            && 0 === $this->nr % $this->args['items_before_each_inject'] )
        {    
            $this->inject_mode = TRUE;          
            $this->results->rewind_posts();
            $this->results->current_post = ( absint( $this->nr / $this->args['items_before_each_inject'] ) -1 ) * $this->args['cpt_items_per_inject'] - 1;
            $j = 1;
            if ( $this->results->have_posts() ) :
                while ( $this->results->have_posts() ) :
                    $this->results->the_post();
                    get_template_part(  $this->args['template_part'] );
                    if( $this->args['cpt_items_per_inject'] < ++$j )
                        break;

                endwhile;
                wp_reset_postdata();
            endif;
            $this->inject_mode = FALSE;
        }

        if( ! $this->inject_mode )
            $this->nr++;

    }
}
```

I tested this on the default theme, where I injected `page` content into the main `post` loop. The pagination seemed to work as well.

This can be refined more, but hopefully this is a starting point for you.

Comment: I went through your thought process and it is perfectly what I have asked for. Just not sure how all of this(post_count, current_post and posts_per_page) will come together. Waiting till you expand the answer. :)

Comment: @thedigitalmonk  I updated the answer, hopefully this first version works for you?

Comment: An outstanding answer.

Comment: Is this still working with the current version of WordPress? I tried to exchange pages and posts with two custom post types and have it appear on the second post type’s archive, inserted both code snippets into my theme’s functions.php, and while the first query returns two posts, no posts are being put out for the second post type at all. May I just have overlooked something, @birgire? Calling the stuff through `<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?><?php endwhile; endif; ?>` in my archive template.

Comment: I just tested this on a WP 4.4.2 install with the default *Twenty Sixteen* theme and it seems to work there with `'template_part' => 'template-parts/content-page'`, maybe that would be a good starting point? It looks like you're missing the display parts, like `the_title()`, in your code and also note the `is_home()` check in the current demo that you might have to adjust. @physalis

Comment: Hey @birgire, this is what I did, for getting a loop (CPT 'work') with each 3rd post being a post from CPT 'testimonial': 1. created content-work.php, put in the bits that should show for a single work entry (e.g. `the_title()`), 2. created content-testimonial.php with the content for single testimonials that appear 3. put the two code snippets from above into functions.php, 4. altered the condition to is_post_type_archive('work') and changed CPT and template bits to right file names, 5. created archive-works.php and called the loop with the code posted above. Did I miss anything?

Comment: @birgire seems you nailed it. In the actual archive page I needed to add in the code for the single work items, not into content-work.php. This is just some minor thing I think I don’t understand, why it is there actually... Anyway, thanks for pointing me into the right direction!

Comment: glad to hear you had some progress, I'm sure it's just a minor thing that was giving you a problem, any way best of luck with the project. @physalis

Comment: @birgire Thanks so much for helping out back then! Is there a way to alter a custom query, e.g. one which I named $projects_query, the same way the main query is being addressed here (so, instead of is_main_query() I suppose)? :)

Comment: I haven't checked, but you could try to skip the is_main_query check and instead try to target a custom WP_Query input variable to target the right instance? @physalis

Comment: @birgire I actually solved it today by using the main query and modifying it with `pre_get_posts` beforehand to fit to my intended usage. This way it's working, though an approach for a custom query would be much more elegant :).

Comment: great, we should use the main query whenever we can ;-) @physalis

Comment: This is brilliant, thanks so much! I've been trying to modify this so that it inserts a cpt after every 2 posts. 

As an example, I have 8 posts but only 3 cpt are showing up (total 11 posts). When I add a 9th post a 4th cpt shows. 

I'd rather the 4th cpt show when 8 posts are there... if that makes sense. Is that possible?

Comment: Glad to hear it helped. I'm not sure I understand, but you could also look into [`the_posts`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/the_posts/) filter to access the post objects array directly and modify it as needed, .e.g. reorder and inject as needed @user1788364.