# Inject post (from specific category) between posts in Loop

Tags: php, posts, categories, wp-query, loop

I would like to add a post (from specific category) between posts in the WordPress Loop (such as 'Sponsors'). Example:

P P P S
P P S P
P S P P

How can I achieve this? I am a beginner with coding, so I don't know enough to modify a Loop on my own. Any Loop Coding Ninjas out there that can provide a solution?

Note that below is my current Loop. It is used to sort posts by price, or by random order:

index.php

```
<?php while (have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
<?php  the_excerpt(); the_meta ();
endwhile; 

previous_posts_link();
next_posts_link();
?>
```

functions.php

```
function my_custom_query($query){
 if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {

  $sort= $_GET['sort'];

  if($sort == "A"){
   $query->set( 'orderby', 'rand' );
   $query->set( 'posts_per_page', '2' );
  }

  if($sort == "B"){
   $query->set( 'meta_key', 'price' );
   $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value_num' );
   $query->set( 'order', 'DESC' );
   $query->set( 'posts_per_page', '2' );
  }
}
}

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_custom_query' );
```

**Edit: Update**

Birgire's plugin works! Initially, I had problems getting the plugin to work on my theme. The problem was this piece of code that I use within the Loop in index.php (I use it to call for the custom field to appear).

```
<?php
    global $wp_query;
    $postid = $wp_query->post->ID;
    echo get_post_meta($postid, 'price', true);
    wp_reset_query();
?>
```

Comment: Glad to hear it worked for you. Notice that you should't use `wp_reset_query()` within the loop, in fact you shouldn't need to call it, ever, except you're using `query_posts()`, which isn't recommended either. Regarding the custom field, use for example `echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'price', true);` instead.

Comment: That is SO much simpler! Thanks so much @birgire!! You've solved all of my issues =) Hope more people can benefit from this plugin.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### The Automatic Sponsor Posts Injector:

Here's one idea based on [my answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/141596/how-to-show-y-number-of-custom-posts-after-every-x-normal-posts) for the question:
[How to show Y number of custom posts after every X normal posts?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/141596/how-to-show-y-number-of-custom-posts-after-every-x-normal-posts)

I hopefully made it a little bit more useful [here on Github](https://gist.github.com/birgire/439e36a6b08f1159f653), but it may be refined much more (future work).

The `SponsorPostsInjector` class will help you to automatically inject the *sponsor* posts into the theme using the filters `the_post`, `loop_start` and `loop_end`.

Activate the plugin and add the following example to your `functions.php` file to start the injections:

```
/**
 * Inject a sponsor post after the first post on the home page,
 * and then again for every third post within the main query.
 */

add_action( 'wp', 'my_sponsor_injections' );

function my_sponsor_injections()
{
    if( ! class_exists( 'SponsorPostsInjector' ) ) return;

    // We want the sponsor posts injections only on the home page:
    if( ! is_home()  ) return;

    // Setup the injection:
    $injector = new SponsorPostsInjector( 
        array(
            'items_before_each_inject' => 3,
            'items_per_inject'         => 1,
            'template_part'            => 'content-sponsor',
        ) 
    );

    // Setup the injection query:
    $injector->query(
        array(
            'post_type'  => 'sponsor',
            'tax_query'  => array( 
                array(
                   'taxonomy' => 'country',
                    'terms'   => 'sweden',    
                    'field'   => 'slug', 
                )
            )
        )
    );

    // Inject:
    $injector->inject();
}
```

where we have created the `content-sponsor.php` template file in our current theme directory, to control the layout of the injected sponsor posts.

The idea is that this should also take care of the pagination.

You can hopefully adjust this to your needs.

Comment: see my reply (made as a comment cause it was too long)

Comment: Since you've read my reply, it is ok to let stackexchange delete my comment. I updated to 0.0.3 and tried it on default themes but no luck. The areas where I likely screw up in is functions.php and content-sponsor.php --- What do you put in content-sponsor.php? a clone of index.php? --- In functions.php the current $injector->query code is for custom post types. How would you code it for regular posts in the category "sponsor" (so I can see if I messed up here)?

Comment: If you try the 2012 theme, you can use `content-page.php` as your testing template part. I also tested it with: `$injector->query(array('category_name' => 'sponsor'));`, that worked as well. Let's see if that works for you. If not then we could try to construct a debug version.

Comment: Hi, birgire, nice answer, +1 of course. Do you mind to add some license info on your repo? Maybe just a `License` header on plugin file. I want to make a fork of your code...

Comment: Thanks @G.M. - I added the GPL2+ license to the plugin, just let me know if it's not suitable. Currently the "draft" plugin is only based on a single class with support for rather old PHP versions, so there are many ways to improve it ;-)

Comment: @birgire Tried it again and it works perfectly in Wordpress 2014 and 2013. However, for 2012, it only shows 2 sponsored posts per page. And sadly, it does not work for my theme (that I made from scratch). The Sponsored Post is positioned within a Regular Post (on the homepage). I deleted style.css so it is not a CSS issue. This is such a great plugin, I really want it to work. If you take a look at my original question above, it includes my loop code for index.php and functions.php --- Does the plugin not work with my loop? Do I need to reset a query or something?

Comment: Thanks to you, @birgire GPL2+ it's perfect for me, I've already done some work, I'll ping you when finished if you want

Comment: @G.M. look forward to it. @leko Great to hear it worked for you in the 2013 and 2014 themes. Strangely I can't reproduce your problems with the 2012 theme and your theme, I even tried your bare `index.php` file above, successfully. The plugin assumes you use `have_posts()` and `the_post()` functions in your main loop. I just want to mention one thing: The plugin is automatically adjusting the `posts_per_page` for the sponsor posts, to fit between the normal posts of the main query and to support pagination. See the examples part of my other answer. I wonder if that's what you're experiencing?

Comment: @birgire https://github.com/Giuseppe-Mazzapica/PostsSyringe I changed approach and completely rewritten code. However mention to you is in main file source.

Comment: @G.M. Awesome work there. I like the idea how you simplified for the user into a single function.