# Skip post in loop and mixin later

Tags: posts, loop

In the blog, i try to avoid to show two posts from the same category in succession. So if the latest two posts are from category 1, i want to skip the second one, take post 3 first (if it's not from category 21 either), and then, mixin the the skiped post before showing number 4.

So what i have is

```
while (have_posts()) : the_post();

    //get category of post
    $categories = get_the_category();
    $category_id = $categories[0]->cat_ID; 

    //set flag to know, when there was a post form category 1
    if ($flag == true && ($category_id == 1)) {

        //store post to use later
        ....

        continue;
    }

    if ($category_id == 1)
        $flag = true;
    else
        $flag = false;

}
```

Anyone has an idea?

Comment: Is there only one category per post? Also, are you only checking for posts in category 1? Wondering why the ID 1 is specified in your example.

Comment: The posts with category 1 have only this category and no other, but other posts might have more categories. And because there are lots of posts from category 1, it should be avoided to see like 10 category1-posts before anothe post comes...

Comment: Have a look at [this post](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/158133/31545). I believe this would help you in your approach.

Comment: So you only want to check if each post is in category 1, correct? Because this gets needlessly difficult if you're having multiple categories per post AND checking for all categories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about an approach like this:

```
$first_category_args = array(
    // category id
    'cat'                 => 123,
    // get all from cat
    'posts_per_page'       => -1,
    // don't prepend sticky
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
    // only return ids
    'fields'              => 'ids'
);
// array of ids
$first_category_query = new WP_Query(
    $first_category_args
);
$first_category_ids = $first_category_query->posts;

$second_category_args = array(
    // category id
    'cat'                 => 456,
    // get all from cat
    'posts_per_page'       => -1,
    // don't prepend sticky
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
    // only return ids
    'fields'              => 'ids'
);
// array of ids
$second_category_query = new WP_Query(
    $second_category_args
);
$second_category_ids = $second_category_query->posts;

// count    
$first_category_ids_count  = count( $first_category_ids );
$second_category_ids_count = count( $second_category_ids );

// set count to the greater one    
if ( $first_category_ids_count > $second_category_ids_count ) {
    $count = $first_category_ids_count;
} else {
    $count = $second_category_ids_count;
}

$combined_alternating_category_ids = array();

// create combined alternating array of ids
for ( $c = 0; $c < $count; $c++ ) {
    if ( isset( $first_category_ids[ $c ] ) ) {
        $combined_alternating_category_ids[] = $first_category_ids[ $c ];
    }
    if ( isset( $second_category_ids[ $c ] ) ) {
        $combined_alternating_category_ids[] = $second_category_ids[ $c ];
    }
}

// now do a query with the combined result
$combined_category_args = array(
    // get post by created alternating ids array
    'post__in' => $combined_alternating_category_ids,
    // we're ordering by the order the ids have in the array
    'orderby'  => 'post__in'
);
$combined_query = new WP_Query(
    $combined_category_args
);

// proceed with a loop
if ( $combined_query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $combined_query->have_posts() ) {
        $combined_query->the_post();
        // show post code
    }
} else {
    // no post code
}

wp_reset_postdata();
```

Just as an idea, <strike>haven't tested this</strike>, gave it a quick test, does work as expected.

---

To alter the main query you can do:

```
function wpse163419_alternate_order_array() {
    $first_category_args = array(
        // category id
        'cat'                 => 1,
        // get all from cat
        'posts_per_page'       => -1,
        // only return ids
        'fields'              => 'ids'
    );
    // array of ids
    $first_category_query = new WP_Query(
        $first_category_args
    );
    $first_category_ids = $first_category_query->posts;

    $second_category_args = array(
        // category id
        'cat'                 => 3,
        // get all from cat
        'posts_per_page'       => -1,
        // only return ids
        'fields'              => 'ids'
    );
    // array of ids
    $second_category_query = new WP_Query(
        $second_category_args
    );
    $second_category_ids = $second_category_query->posts;

    // count    
    $first_category_ids_count  = count( $first_category_ids );
    $second_category_ids_count = count( $second_category_ids );

    // set count to the greater one    
    if ( $first_category_ids_count > $second_category_ids_count ) {
        $count = $first_category_ids_count;
    } else {
        $count = $second_category_ids_count;
    }

    $combined_alternating_category_ids = array();

    // create combined alternating array of ids
    for ( $c = 0; $c < $count; $c++ ) {
        if ( isset( $first_category_ids[ $c ] ) ) {
            $combined_alternating_category_ids[] = $first_category_ids[ $c ];
        }
        if ( isset( $second_category_ids[ $c ] ) ) {
            $combined_alternating_category_ids[] = $second_category_ids[ $c ];
        }
    }

    return $combined_alternating_category_ids;
}

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse163419_cat_alternate_order' );
function wpse163419_cat_alternate_order( $query ) {
    // avoid infinite loop
    remove_action( 'pre_get_posts', __FUNCTION__ );
    // get ids
    $combined_alternating_category_ids = wpse163419_alternate_order_array();
    // set query parameter
    if ( ! is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'post__in', $combined_alternating_category_ids );
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'post__in' );
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', '-1' );
    }
}
```

Comment: I like your approach. This is, IMO, the better approach to take here. I had the same in mind. I really think that the OP missed one important thing here, what happens if you have 8 posts from cat one and just 2 from other cats in the loop. This issue has been addressed here. You get my +1 on this.

Comment: Thanks @PieterGoosen It is kind of neat, especially because this kind of setup can easily be varied. And it is fairly robust, which is always a good thing. I don't like the three queries, actually pretty much hate that. But of course one can just suggest what one knows. On the other hand, I'm pretty much certain that alternating orders can be done via SQL, I'm just not good enough with it to suggest this kind of solution.

Answer (score 1):

This stores a variable to check if the most recently displayed post was in category 1. If the next post is also in category 1, it adds it to an array of stored posts.

This allows you to store multiples posts in case you have many category 1 posts in a row.

Finally it spits out all stored posts if you've reached the last item in the loop.

```
    $prev_cat1 = '';
    $count = 0;
    $stored_posts = array();

    while (have_posts()) : the_post();

        // Starting counting posts so we know if we reach the end of the loop
        $count++;

        // Check if post is in category 1
        $categories = wp_get_post_categories();
        if(in_array('1', $categories)){
            $cat1 = true;
        }else{
            $cat1 = false;
        }

        //check if previous post category is the same
        if ($cat1 && $prev_cat1) {

            // Store the post ID and category in an array for later use (must use array in case there are multiple posts in a row with same category)
            $stored_posts[] = get_the_ID();

        }else{

            // YOUR POST CONTENT

            // Specify whether or not this post was in category 1
            if($cat1) $prev_cat1 = true;
            else $prev_cat1 = false;

        }

        // Check if there is a stored post AND that the previous displayed post was not in category 1
        if(!empty($stored_posts) && !$prev_cat1){

             // YOUR POST CONTENT
             // make sure to specify the post ID since you're not using the current post in the loop, eg. echo get_the_title($postID);

            // Remove that post from the stored posts array
            array_shift($stored_posts);

            // Specify that last printed post was in category 1
            $prev_cat1 = true;

        }

        // If this was the last post in the loop, just output the remaining stored posts
        if($count == sizeof($posts)){
            foreach($stored_posts as $post){

                // YOUR POST CONTENT (same note as above about specifying the post ID)

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In the end i made two queries, the first one to get the ids of the posts and the second one to give back the posts in the type of sorting i wanted to:

```
$flag = false;

//arguments for first query
$args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'posts_per_page' => 500,
);

$query = new WP_Query($args);

//make first query only to get the ids
while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();

    //get category of post
    $categories = get_the_category();
    $category_id = $categories[0]->cat_ID;          

     if (($category_id == 1)) {

        //if it is second appearence of cat1 post
        $postToSave[] = $post->ID;
        $flag = true;

    } else if ($flag == true && ($category_id != 1)) {

        //if flag is true, mixin from array
        $defaultPost[] = $post->ID;

        if (!empty($postToSave)) {
            $idSavedPosts = array_shift($postToSave);
            $defaultPost[] = $idSavedPosts;
            $flag = true;
        }

    } else if ($flag == false && ($category_id != 1)) {

        // flag is false, just add no normal array
        $defaultPost[] = $post->ID;
        $flag = false;

        if (!empty($postToSave)) {
            $idSavedPosts = array_shift($postToSave);
            $defaultPost[] = $idSavedPosts;
        }
    }

endwhile;
```

and the second one with this arguments:

```
$args2 = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'posts_per_page' => 12,
        'paged' => ( get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1),
        'post__in' => $defaultPost,
        'orderby' =>'post__in'
);
```

Thanks for your help! Brought me to the right direction