# Insert single CPT items every x posts of another CPT

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query

I know there is something similar already discussed [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/141596/how-to-show-y-number-of-custom-posts-after-every-x-normal-posts), but I cannot seem to get my head around this to fit my current project and needs.

For a portfolio, on a query of portfolio entries (custom post type called 'work'), the main CPT query should be paused after every two portfolio entries and one post of another custom post type (custom post type: 'testimonial') should be inserted, right until all 'work' items have been put out. The layout for each post type’s single entry is completely different.

With the given solution to the similar task in the question above I am not really able to piece together an archive page with a single query as it seems. Furthermore, I believe it does not allow for showing all 'work' posts and inserting 'testimonials' breakers until all 'work' posts are shown. Pagination is not needed at all.
Any advice would be really appreciated!

A simple representation of what I mean:

```
<div class="portfolio_list">
    <div class="portfolio_item"></div>
    <div class="portfolio_item"></div>

    <div class="testimonial_element" id="testimonial_1">Some different content</div>

    <div class="portfolio_item"></div>
    <div class="portfolio_item"></div>

    <div class="testimonial_element" id="testimonial_2">Some different content</div>


    <div class="portfolio_item"></div>
    <div class="portfolio_item"></div>

    <div class="testimonial_element" id="testimonial_3">Some different content</div>

    <div class="portfolio_item"></div>
    <div class="portfolio_item"></div>
    ...
</div>
```

Comment: You should not have an issue here. Just be sure that you are not making use of a custom query to run the page

Comment: So I would basically have to cater the condition to be the post type archive of 'work' instead of home page, and I call it from the standard query from the archive template?

Comment: Alas, I tried out the approach from the other post. Replaced pages with work and posts with testimonial, but no more than two testimonials are being put out. I suspect it to be somehow related to the kind of post type being used. Since you have to specify the amount of total posts being put out, I assume this is somehow breaking it.